# Losing database session data on 2nd page

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have written a class to store my session data into my database (see below). All works fine with the first page load after logging in, I see the data in the database.

However, moving on to the next page, print_r($_SESSION) returns an empty array, and the database entry has been updated to set the data column to nothing, but updated the access column accordingly.

EDIT: to confirm, the row with the existing session ID is being updated, as the access column has the new time value, but the data field is no blank.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyProject;

use \PDO;


class Session
{
    private $dblayer;
    private $user_agent;

    public function __construct(PDO $dblayer)
    {
        $this->dblayer = $dblayer;
        $this->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, 'open'),
            array($this, 'close'),
            array($this, 'read'),
            array($this, 'write'),
            array($this, 'destroy'),
            array($this, 'gc')
        );

        if ('LIVE' == DEVELOPMENT_MODE) {
            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', true, true);
        } else {
            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', false, true);
        }

        session_start();

    }

    public function checkUserAgent()
    {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] === $this->user_agent) {
            session_regenerate_id(true);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function open()
    {
        if ($this->dblayer) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        $this->dblayer = null;
        if (!$this->dblayer) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

            if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
                return $data['data'];
            }

            return '';

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // will use file_put_contents to save error message, file etc to error log
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {

            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES(:id, :data, NOW())");
            $stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

            if ($stmt) {
                return true;
            }

            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // can i save to error log here?
            return false;

    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // again, will save error data to log
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function gc($max)
    {
        $to_delete = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time() - $max);

        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE access < :to_delete");
            $stmt->bindParam(':to_delete', $to_delete);

            $this->dblayer->commit();

            return true;

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // save error data to log;
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: In your code, you are using `rollBack`, could that be causing the issue? Something is failing so it is rolling back?

Comment: That's a good point, although it writes perfectly fine the first time?

Comment: How is your `id` field determined, meaning is it unique on each hit?

Comment: The query is using replace_into, and the id field is my primary key, so it inserts, unless a primary key matches, in which case it deletes that row before inserting. The access column is updating fine

Comment: Well, I ask because maybe an ID is cannot be found on refresh because it changes, or maybe because the `data` field changes so the query fails and rollbacks, could that be a possibility? Also, this is the first time I've come across the `REPLACE` clause so I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Comment: The ID is found, because the row does update, so it can't be rolling back. The access column updates to the new time, so the query is running successfully

Answer (score 0):

Check if Session is there when the second page is called and recall session_start if it's not.

Comment: I instantiate the Session class on the following page and therefore session_start() is called in the __construct method

Answer (score 0):

On the second page make sure to place session_start(); , just double check , you might overlook.

Comment: I instantiate the Session class on the following page and therefore session_start() is called in the __construct method

Answer (score 0):

Whilst most similar cases are unlikely to have the exact cause mine did, the issue does emphasise the need to understand when and how each of the session methods are called. The problem was in fact in the read() method, where I was not binding the id parameter.

Missing line:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
```

So anybody having the same issue, check all methods!